# Windows sometimes forces me to ctrl + alt + del to unlock it

Tags: windows-10, lock-screen

When I unlock my home PC, I often get in a situation like this:

- background is the current windows lock screen image
- no text like "press ctrl+alt+del"
- no field to type my password
- if I click or press any key, I get the windows "[background](https://youtu.be/sRTvrtuuGJQ?t=177)" sound, like when there's a window open that has priority over the one you're clicking. Nothing happens, the field doesn't show up.

When this happens, I don't know if it solves by waiting because I don't have the patience, but if I press ctrl+alt+del the password prompt shows up and I can login. This means I have to press ctrl+alt+del almost every time I want to login even though it's not enabled. When this "bug" happens I also don't see the little texts on the Windows lock screen images.

And after I log in, there's no window awaiting for my action. Today for example I just had Firefox and task manager open.

Clarification: This doesn't happen all the time. Sometimes I get the normal behavior, which is no password field, and any key makes it appear. The bug can happen when I come back from hibernation or after a normal startup.

What could be causing this and how can I avoid it?

Answer (score 1):

I often check Windows Screen Saver settings first. It may be the the setting you have causing the issue.

If additional work is needed, try the regular initial repairs. Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator and run DISM followed by SFC.

In my experience, settings are normally the issue but try repairing the system. Also update your Power Drivers and BIOS.

dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /restoreheath and then

SFC /SCANNOW Restart after all the above.

Also make sure you have a password on your Windows account and that is the account you are using.

Now, failing all of the above, the next step is a Windows 10 Repair Install. This is straightforward to do and repairs many issue. Go to the Microsoft Media Creation Link and use the second option, run in place, and then when it comes up, choose the option to Keep Everything.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Comment: I really don't think this is a setting, because it doesn't happen all the time. Normal behavior is: No password field, when any key is pressed it appears. That's what I *sometimes* have. The situation I'm describing is: No password field, any key rings an alert sound. The only thing I can do to type my password is ctrl+alt+del.

Comment: Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator and run DISM followed by SFC.  In my experience, settings are normally the issue but try repairing the system. Also update your Power Drivers and BIOS.

dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restoreheath   and then   
SFC /SCANNOW  

Restart after all the above.

Comment: @John add this to your answer please.

Comment: Thank you for your help, and I have done so. Good idea.

Comment: It's not a settings problem (I don't think you've read my question correctly, you're not describing my situation. Pressing a key **does not** make the prompt appear, it rings an alert sound), and I ran your commands, the problem's still here. Do you have something else I could try?

Comment: I try settings first as it is the easiest thing to check. Since the initial repairs did not work, the next step is a repair install. I modified my answer to reduce the first part and add the Windows 10 Repair

Answer (score 1):

I have had this happen on my work PC a few times. I don't know what causes it, or how to prevent it, but I do at least have a solution to make the problem go away when it occurs!

I had already checked both the User Accounts "Secure sign-in" setting and the Local Security Policy setting, neither was the culprit. I had also tried running a `gpupdate /force`, which also did not fix it.

But what did fix it, for me, was after pressing Ctrl-Alt-Del to get the password prompt, I subsequently clicked on **Switch User** down in the bottom left corner of the screen. Then, after logging in with my username and password, I pressed Win-L to return to the lock screen and sure enough, just a mouse click or keyboard key press were enough to show the password prompt again!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably relatead with a non-standard screensaver. For me the problem is with gPhotoShow Screen Saver. If you disable the screen saver or use a one that's built-in everything should work fine.

You can verify that the screen saver is a problem by doing this:

1. Reproduce the lock screen problem.
2. Unlock with CTRL+ALT+DELETE.
3. Open screen saver settings and press Preview.
4. Lock your station (Win+L).
5. Check if you can click to show password.

So that seems like some incompatibility on windows 10 side. It's weird that a screensaver running in the background can mess up something like a system's lock screen. Might even be a security bug Windows 10.

See also:
https://www.displayfusion.com/Discussions/View/windows-10-lockscreen-won39t-unlock/?ID=6ce63803-5db3-4e80-bf9c-80569c3d28c9

Comment: I'm not using a non-standard screensaver. I'll look at your link though.